# What do you say when you want to reject a gift without offending anyone?

Tags: politeness, phrase-requests, culture

If you are offered something that you don't want, what do you say to reject it politely?

Comment: What is that kind of gift?
Someone wanted to give me something (I forgot), I said my room is too small, so I cannot get it.

Comment: It seems that there is a phrase that works on everything!

Comment: My room is really small :D 5畳 :((

Answer (score 6):

I will say like 申し訳ないけど、～なので受け取れないんです。

I think you should explain the reason why you reject the gift. For example, if I am presented a whole cake and reject it, I will say like 申し訳ないけど、ダイエット中なので受け取れないんです。

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker and just a beginning learner, but I just learned that one way to say it is 気持ちだけ受け取（る・ります）よ。

It means something along the lines of "Thank you for your kindness, but I shall politely decline." Literally, it means "I'll accept only your (kind) feelings."